# using AppData location in NLog

Tags: nlog

My NLog targets is like this:

```xml
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="Console" name="console" 
    layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message}" />
  <target xsi:type="File" name="ErrorLog" fileName="${basedir}/error.txt"
          layout="${longdate}
          Trace: ${stacktrace} 
          ${message}" />
  <target xsi:type="File" name="AccessLog" fileName="${basedir}/access.txt"
          layout="${shortdate} | ${message}" />
</targets>
```

But this causes problems if the user isn't an admin on their machine, because they will not have write access to "Program Files". How can I get something like `%AppData%` to NLog instead of BaseDir?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You're looking for the [NLog special folders](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer).

Example:

```
...fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/Program/file.txt"...
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I use it? I've already tried, fileName="${ApplicationData}/RentalEase/access.txt" and it fails silently.

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head, but it should look like this:

${specialfolder:folder=SPECIALFOLDERNAME}

Comment: ${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}

Comment: I missread that, thought you had a '.' between specialfolder and folder instead of a colon

Comment: If it fails silently try adding `<nlog throwExceptions="true" />` - ref: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#troubleshooting-logging

Answer (score 13):

Oren's answer should be the right answer.  However, for the life of me I couldn't get it to work with my .NET 4.0 website using nLog 2.0.0.0.  I ended up using simply

```
fileName="${basedir}app_data\logs\${shortdate}.log"
```

Comment: The question title uses "AppData" but I don't think {..ApplicationData} is mapped to App_Data, I'd have to read the source to double check.

Comment: This question and accepted answer is about the Windows special folder %appdata%, typically C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming. It seems there is no special variable for the ASP.net App_Data folder.

Answer (score 7):

${specialfolder:ApplicationData} also works

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers helped solve the problem I was having, but a couple of years later and the solution is now somewhat different under v4.3. The directory and filename are combined with the path.

@theGecko's link is still current for the syntax, but the page is deficient of an example:

https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer

The following example would write the file `myLog.log` to the current users application data roaming directory `C:\USers\current.user\AppData\Roaming\My\Path\Somewhere`:

```
fileName="${specialfolder:dir=My/Path/Somewhere/:file=myFile.log:folder=ApplicationData}"
```

Answer (score 1):

**For logging to the project directory:**

While the previous answers work for the original question, searching for how to log to the project `APP_DATA` directory leads to this question. And while [bkaid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5426511/2386514)'s answer works for ASP.NET and for using the `APP_DATA` folder specifically, for .NET Core and .NET 5 the solution is a bit different, because that motif has been abandoned in favor of defining a `wwwroot` folder for only those things which should be served, and the remainder being private. The answer for .NET Core/5, then, is to write to the solution root directory:

1. First, ensure the `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` assembly is added to `nlog.config`:

   ```xml
   <extensions>
       <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
   </extensions>
   ```
2. Then use one of the layout renderers provided by that extension, in this case `${aspnet-appbasepath}` which references the solution root directory:

   ```xml
   <targets>
       <target name="file"
               type="File"
               xsi:type="File"
               fileName="${aspnet-appbasepath}/log/${shortdate}.log"
               layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id:whenEmpty=0}"/>
   </targets>
   ```

This will write the file to `<solution folder>/log/2021-07-01.log`, which will never be served by the public-facing website. Other layout renderers provided by this assembly are [listed on the NLog website](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore).